# How to change video subtitles font size in html5?

Tags: html, webvtt

My **html** looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
            <source src="videoPath" type="video/mp4">
            <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="subs.vtt" default>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

as **subs.vtt** is the subtitles file.

How do I change the subtitles size attached to the `track` element?

I tried creating a **css** file, then gave the `track` an **id** and specified its `font-size` in the **css**, and of course linked the **css** to the **html**, but the size didn't change.

I also tried styling inside the **.vtt** file itself:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:43.889 --> 00:00:46.949 size:200%
<i>Introduction...</i>
```

and it didn't change the size.

I tried also something like this that I found online:

```
WEBVTT
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
1
00:00:43.889 --> 00:00:46.949
<c vIntro><i>Introduction...</i></c>
```

and in **css**:

```
.vIntro{
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

but also this didn't change the size.

I prefer a way without touching the **.vtt** file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It's 2021, more than six years after the original answer was written, and [Shadow DOM has much wider support with a changed spec](https://caniuse.com/shadowdomv1).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

In [browsers that support Shadow DOM](https://caniuse.com/shadowdom), you can style the subtitles. It may vary from browser to browser, but in Chrome 42 (current as of this writing), you can use this CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

Given that there's a vendor prefix in there, I imagine other browsers might require additional rules. Then again, there aren't that many browsers that support Shadow DOM. As of this writing, it's just Chrome, Opera, and Android/Chrome-for-Android.

Answer (score 4):

It is an old subject but still in the first results in google. So here is my answer.

For firefox (I do not know for others browsers), you can put this in your css :

```
::cue {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```